# How to design listview viewcell design in Xamarin forms?

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin forms and I'm unable to create a design like this; how do I create this view cell design, using Xaml or CS code in Xamarin?

List View Design:

[image]

Comment: Do you have to have a viewcell? I would advice for a list of Frames. This will better depict the image you provided. I can give you that code if you agree?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three major components that compose this layout. The "Scoreboard", "PlayerFrame", and "Checkbox". Mainly you have your Scoreboard and PlayerFrame, but in order to create a checkbox in Xamarin Forms I had to create a custom renderer. I changed some of the colors and general placement of some visual elements. Does the following image accurately depict what you are looking for? I would like to make sure before I post all the code for the bounty.

[image: Bounty Theme]

Answer (score 0):

```
<ListView ItemsSOurce="{Binding Players}" RowHeight="75">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid BackgroundColor="Gray">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="15"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ContentView Grid.RowSpan="2" BackgroundColor="Blue">
                <Label Text="{Binding PlayerId}" Rotation="90" TextColor="White"/>
            </ContentView>
                <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Date}" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="Red" HorizontalOptions="End"/>

                ...

            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have recently created a package called XamarinForms.CardView that could help you with this style. You can find it [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/XamarinForms.CardView/).
I have used it and used Kowalski answer to combine what you want, have a look:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:cardView="clr-namespace:CardView;assembly=CardView"
             x:Class="SO.ListPage">
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Text="Sort:" />

    </StackLayout>
    <ListView SeparatorVisibility="None" ItemsSource="{Binding Players}" RowHeight="150" HasUnevenRows="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <cardView:CardView Margin="5" CardViewOutlineColor="Black" CardViewOutlineColorThickness="2" CardViewOutlineColorHasShadow="True">
                        <cardView:CardView.CardViewContent>
                            <Grid BackgroundColor="Gray">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <StackLayout Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="Blue" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding PlayerNumber}" Rotation="270" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalTextAlignment="Start" Margin="0,0,0,30"></Label>
                                </StackLayout>
                                <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding Date}" BackgroundColor="Red" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
                                <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Number}" FontSize="20" BackgroundColor="White" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"></Label>
                                <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding RandomText}" TextColor="Maroon"></Label>
                            </Grid>
                        </cardView:CardView.CardViewContent>
                    </cardView:CardView>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

The result I got was simple and here it is:
 [image: Design using XAML]

Note that to have a Circle as a background you need to use a custom package or an image as a background because it's not supported directly in `Xamarin.Forms` as well as the radio buttons you wanted.
I have found this https://guido1993.wordpress.com/2015/06/17/how-to-draw-shapes-in-xamarin-forms/ but I didn't try it.

#### EDIT:

I have edited my code a little bit, and here's the new code and the new image result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:cardView="clr-namespace:CardView;assembly=CardView"
             x:Class="SO.ListPage">
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Text="Sort:" />

    </StackLayout>
    <ListView SeparatorVisibility="None" ItemsSource="{Binding Players}" RowHeight="150" HasUnevenRows="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <cardView:CardView CardViewInnerPadding="20" Margin="5">
                        <cardView:CardView.CardViewContent>
                            <Grid BackgroundColor="Gray">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <StackLayout Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="Blue" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding PlayerNumber}" Rotation="270" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalTextAlignment="Start" Margin="0,0,0,30"></Label>
                                </StackLayout>
                                <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding Date}" BackgroundColor="Red" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Margin="0,10,-10,0"/>
                                <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Number}" FontSize="20" BackgroundColor="White" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"></Label>
                                <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding RandomText}" TextColor="Maroon"></Label>
                            </Grid>
                        </cardView:CardView.CardViewContent>
                    </cardView:CardView>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

[image: Second Code Image Result]